# Conversión datos binarios .RTF y .DOT de una Base de Datos a texto plano

Tags: java, sql-server

Estoy utilizando java para recibir y manipular datos de una Base SQL Server y tengo que transformar datos .DOT y .RTF que vienen de esta BD a texto plano para poder mostrarlo a través de la aplicación sin caracteres extraños.

Los datos están almacenados en una columna tipo image.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la imagen se ve que el contenido no es apto para ser mostrado sin antes transformarlo a texto plano. No encuentro en internet ninguna solución porque todos los métodos de conversión de archivos que encuentro leen el fichero de una ruta del equipo, pero yo los datos no los tomo de mi ordenador, sino en una Base de Datos.

Si me pudiera alguien indicar como hacer esta conversión me sería de gran ayuda.
!Muchas gracias¡

Comment: Puedes leer los datos y crear un fichero temporal con ellos.

Comment: Las bases de datos de SQL Server no manejan datos .DOT o .RTF. Encuentra el proceso que hicieron para pasarlos de eso al tipo image (que debería ser actualizado a un tipo varbinary) y haz el proceso contrario.